# Problema com SMTP phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, smtp

Estou com o seguinte erro :

> "Erro: SMTP Error: Data not accepted."

Ontem estava funcionando bem, hoje começou dar esse erro.

Ontem o pessoal do marketing usou para mandar mensagem em massa, estou achando que possa ser o servidor que excedeu a capacidade.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
          $mail->IsSMTP();
          $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
          $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
          $mail->Host       = "smtp.office365.com"; // SMTP server
          $mail->Port       = "587";
          $mail->From       = "meu@email";//remetente
          $mail->Username   = "meu@email";
          $mail->Password   = "minhaSEnha";
          $mail->FromName   = "Empresa | Administração";
          $mail->AddReplyTo("meu@email");
          $mail->AddAddress($variavelcomemailcliente);
          $mail->Subject = "titulo da menssagem";
          $mail->IsHTML(true);

      $mail->AddAddress($variavelcomemailcliente);

      if($emailcliente!=$variavelcomemailcliente){
        $mail->AddBCC($emailcliente);
      }

      //
      $mail->AddBCC("meu@email", "Empresa");

      $mail->Body = $html;

          if(!$mail->Send())
         {
            echo "Mensagem não foi enviada!";
            echo "Erro: " .$mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, isto pode ocorrer por vários motivos. Como você mesmo mencionou o envio em massa geralmente é bloqueado devido spam entre outros.

Te aconselho a acrescentar esta linha de código no seu script `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;`
Pois assim você terá um retorno completo e exato do que está ocorrendo e não somente isto: **"Erro: SMTP Error: Data not accepted."**

aqui `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;` além do int 1, você pode usar os abaixos também, que sempre te auxiliará para debugar erros:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //Alternative to above constant

SMTP::DEBUG_OFF (0): Disable debugging (you can also leave this out completely, 0 is the default).
SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT (1): Output messages sent by the client.
SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER (2): as 1, plus responses received from the server (this is the most useful setting).
SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION (3): as 2, plus more information about the initial connection - this level can help diagnose STARTTLS failures.
SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL (4): as 3, plus even lower-level information, very verbose, don't use for debugging SMTP, only low-level problems.
```

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo, sua dica foi muito útil, ele me retornou esse erro agora  ERRO: Os dados não são aceitos pelo servidor: xxxxxxx caixa de correio cheia; agora sei que o problema dever ser o armazenamento, só tenho uma duvida, o armazenamento e no meu Servidor, onde o sistema esta hospedado, ou e a caixa de entrada do e-mail que usamos no caso aqui officer 365.

Comment: @JardelAraujo boa tarde, olha eu acredito ser o office 365, mas também pode ser seu servidor. Acredito que você consiga resolver. Pois agora filtrou o problema. Veja qual o email que está enviando via smtp, marque esta conta como ilimitada. Depois verifique se seu servidor há alguma trava de armazenamento. Espero ter ajudado. Abraço